# Groovy Grape configuration on intellij idea 13.1

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, groovy-console

I have recently migrated to IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 and I'm using it with groovy 2.3. I have used the IDE's support for grab annotations in groovy scripts where with just the key stroke of alt+return the IDE smartly downloads grab dependencies and adds it to the projects classpath. But all of a sudden it has stopped working and I have no clue what's wrong. It also does not log anything specific other that it can't find the dependencies. The same script works perfectly fine when launched from groovy console.

Let me know if anybody has encountered this or if you know where to look for the problem.

Comment: Can't find the dependencies? Make sure your `.grails` folder is where it's supposed to be. Check your Aether configuration to make sure your dependency management is all set up properly. Has your environment changed? (New Proxy etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a proxy setting issue. There is no way to override the proxy settings for grapes in the IDE. So the IDE proxy settings were affecting Grapes download.